# Enumerating a OrderedEnumerable changes the order?

Tags: c#, selenium, linq

```
// elements is of type ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>
var elements = Context.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(path));
// sortedElements is of type OrderedEnumerable<IWebElement, int> 
var sortedElements = elements.OrderBy(a => a.point.Y); // a.point.Y is a Point object (so ordering by int)

// inspecting sortedElements here produces the correct sorting by a.point.Y

foreach (var row in sortedElements.ToList()) {
   System.Console.WriteLine(row.point.Y); 
   // here, the rows are no longer in sorted order even though sortedElements is sorted?  
   // i.e., row.point.Y's are not being logged with correct sorting
}
```

I have tried casting elements to .ToList() or .ToArray() (same with sortedElements). It's baffling me why sortedElements is clearly sorted but when I enumerate it, the enumeration is happening in a non-sorted order. I thought ToList() was supposed to preserve order.. does anyone know what may be going on here?

Comment: What is  the`Y` type?

Comment: Of course, `ToList()` preserve the order by. Maybe the value `IWebElement.point.Y` is variant. In this case, the value used to sort and the value displayed for each row will be different.

Comment: I tried reproducing this (using .NET 6) with both a class and a struct, and could not. See [https://dotnetfiddle.net/8RBzop](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8RBzop)  The only thing I don't have is the `Context`. Is that FindElements async? Is is possible that the results are changing in real-time and they are sorted, they just aren't the numbers you're expecting to see?